# Regex to match 3 zeroes in the string of digits

Tags: python, regex

Let's say I have strings like this one, and I need to get rid of three 0 in it. I need to get rid of the last three ones. The numbers that should be created after removing these zeroes can consist only of 2 or 3 digits.

Probably the best idea would be to somehow tell regex to only match when the pattern of `000` is followed by digits from `[1-9]` and exclude `[1-9]` from it. However, I have no idea how to do that.

```
76000123000100000101000 ---> 76 123 100 101
```

Is it possible to do with regex? I tried many different patterns, but I can't find the right one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```py
re.sub(r'000(?=[1-9]|$)', ' ', x).strip()
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/Jyn1HT/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  000                      '000'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [1-9]                    any character of: '1' to '9'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

[**Python code**](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEolasoNT21QsFWoUjJwMBAw9422lDXMrZGRVOJqyS1uCS@uKQIKKlkbgaUNTQyBpEGBmASRCsBtReX5pSA9KfqFZcmaYCN01FQUlDSUYAZoKkHJDILNDS5Cooy80o0IHo0//8HAA):

```py
import re
regex = r"000(?=[1-9]|$)"
test_str = "76000123000100000101000"
result = re.sub(regex, " ", test_str).strip()
print(result)
```

**Results**: `76 123 100 101`

Comment: `000(?!0)` should be enough I think

Answer (score 1):

Other options getting the last 3 zeroes are using a negative lookahead `(?!` asserting not a zero at the right.

```
000(?!0)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YjBTaS/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/lss3eD)

```
import re
 
print(re.sub(r'000(?!0)', ' ', '76000123000100000101000').strip())
```

Or using a capture group, matching 3 zeroes and capture what follows using that in the replacement:

```
000([1-9]|$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sKPOEV/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/NkymFx)

```
import re
 
print(re.sub(r'000([1-9]|$)', r'\1 ', '76000123000100000101000').strip())
```

**Output**

```
76 123 100 101
```